# Http Method Gets Rewritten - Post => Get

Tags: c#, .net-core

This is driving me cray cray, I have the following code:

```
public WorkItemQueryResult GetListOfStories(string queryString, string tfsInstance, string PAT)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", $"{GetPatAsEncodedString(PAT)}");

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(queryString)),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri($"{tfsInstance}_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1")
        };

        var task = Task.Run(() => client.SendAsync(request)); 
        task.Wait();

        if (!task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode) return new WorkItemQueryResult();

        var response = task.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<WorkItemQueryResult>();
        return response.Result;
    }
```

Which when I debug it with a break point on Task.Run shows the following:
[image: HttpRequestMessage with Method == Post]

My issue is that after executing the method I get an error from Azure DevOps telling me that the method isn't allowed. Here's the request after task.Wait:

[image: Request after task.wait]

I've verified that the same body and auth headers work through another client (YaRC). Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I can't see it :(

Comment: In your screenshots your first method is a `POST` but the second one is a `GET`

Comment: Also you don't need to wrap the `client.SendAsync(request)` in `Task.Run()`. The call already returns a task so just do `var task = client.SendAsync(request)` and you can still await the task.

Comment: @SimplyGed, yes I realise the method changes but I haven't been able to work out why or how the http method changes. Was hoping someone could point out something I'm doing wrong that would resolve this.

Normally I'd await but the console app that I'm adding the logic to isn't asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry I worded that wrong. You can change it to `var task = client.SendAsync(request)` and still call `task.Wait()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Know its been a bit but, the issue ended up being that when a 3xx redirect is returned, the Authorization header is cleared out for security. So the POST is redirecting, causing a GET to be sent without authorization, resulting in 405.

The original request URL was http and as a result were getting redirected to https. Which then caused the above to occur :)

Comment: Man this old response jsut saved my day...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try using 'ConfigureAwait' and 'GetAwaiter' like bellow:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => client.SendAsync(request)); 
//task.Wait();
task.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter();
```